std::regex_match with custom string class
I'm trying to perform a regex on a string of custom characters and I'm stuck with MSVC 2015, C++11.
Is there any way to do this without converting my string to a std::u32string e.g.? I'd like to avoid the memory allocation and byte copying to a temporary object.
Here's a small example:
#include <regex>
struct MyChar {
    char32_t c;
    int color_id;
    
    MyChar(char32_t wc) { c=wc; color_id=1; }
    operator char32_t()const { return c; }

    MyChar() { c=0;  color_id= 1; }
    MyChar(const MyChar& c) = default;
    const MyChar& operator=(const MyChar& cc) { c=cc.c; color_id=cc.color_id; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const MyChar& c2)const { return c==c2.c; }
    bool operator!=(const MyChar& c2)const { return c!=c2.c; }
};



int main(int, char**) {
    std::vector<MyChar> line = {U'H', U'e', U'l', U'l', U'o', U' ', U'W', U'o', U'r', U'l', U'd'};
    std::regex rx(R"(\b(hello|world)\b)", std::regex::icase);
    std::match_results<std::vector<MyChar>::const_iterator> matches;
    if(std::regex_match(line.begin(), line.end(), rx, matches)) { // ERROR HERE
    }
}

Here's the error:
main.cpp:22:8: error: no matching function for call to 'regex_match'
    if(std::regex_match(line.begin(), line.end(), rx, matches)) { // ERROR HERE
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6235:1: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'std::match_results<std::vector<MyChar>::const_iterator>' (aka 'match_results<__wrap_iter<const MyChar *>>') to 'regex_constants::match_flag_type' for 4th argument
regex_match(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6214:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'match_results' against 'basic_regex'
regex_match(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6246:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<MyChar *>')
regex_match(const _CharT* __str, match_results<const _CharT*, _Allocator>& __m,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6256:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against '__wrap_iter'
regex_match(const basic_string<_CharT, _ST, _SA>& __s,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6268:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against '__wrap_iter'
regex_match(const basic_string<_CharT, _ST, _SA>&& __s,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6277:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at most 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
regex_match(const _CharT* __str, const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __e,
^
/root/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/regex:6286:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at most 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
regex_match(const basic_string<_CharT, _ST, _SA>& __s,
^
1 error generated.

Test it here[1]
[1] test it online

What error do you get? Please copy-paste in question.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits - I read this line "To use std::basic_regex with other character types (for example, char32_t), a user-provided trait class must be used." basic_regex is a template function which expects Traits. `template<
class CharT,
class Traits = std::regex_traits

class basic_regex;`


std::regex_match(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), matches, rx) Match result goes first, then regex.  Once that is fixed, you'll get a different error, caused by trying to mix MyChar and char
